# Bidirectional power flow USB

Tags: power-supply, usb

I am thinking of a new project that would involve a Raspberry Pi, a UPS, and an Arduino enclosed in a robot structure, with the ability to charge the UPS and also power other devices not on the robot using the same wire. I would also like to have the datalines intact for this.

I am unsure how to do this, so I am asking here, as this seems the most likely place for it. Please see attached image for rough outline. I can clarify if needed.

[image: Power and Comms Issue Diagram]

I know this is possible, as some phones can have their charge port be used to power things like Square and others.

I am planning on using [this UPS](https://www.pishop.ca/product/pi-uptime-ups-board-for-raspberry-pi/) for the project.

Comment: It's up to the UPS board features? What does the manual about the features?

Comment: @Justme from what I read, it seems to be dumb device, with the power in for the UPS just straddling the 5V and gnd lines. No actual communication seems to take place. I sent a message to Alchemy Power to verify, but for discussion, let's assume there is no data connection

Comment: XY problem. You tell us what parts make your "thing" but then you say you are unsure about how to do this and you show a picture with question marks in it. XY problem because nobody knows what you are trying to accomplish let alone what data lines you refer to.

Comment: @Andyaka What I am trying to do is have something that goes in front of the UPS which is a dumb device so power can be shoved into the UPS when the left most arrows are powered externally. Data however is to behave like it is a usb plugged into the Raspbery Pi's USB sockets, thus allowing the single connector to be like a phone's usb port: A source and sink of power, and data.

Comment: @Justme I just verified with the UPS company, the USB data lines are deadended on the device, they go nowhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this in the future, the way the Raspberry Pi 4 is configured is such that the port cannot act bidirectionally. Plugging in a USB cable into the power port, even if it could get power, does not make it connect to the computer. Thus the idea I had does not make sense in the first place. The way the Pi is built according to [this other post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100583/where-is-the-usb2-otg-port-on-the-rpi-4-model-b-located), means that it can only be a slave device

I have changed my design to use one of the Pi's output ports as an output line, and the UPS input as an input line and switch between the 2 mechanically